# Outlook 365 searches emails in server by default. How to change this?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook 365 searches emails in server by default.
If there is a problem with the network, then after a while Outlook provides the option for searching locally, see figure (in Spanish).

**How can I change the default to search locally?**

[image]

Translation:

> There was a problem and the search could not be completed..
>
> There is a problem with the network connection.
>
> Search email messages stored in this PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an expected behavior when using Exchange account in Outlook 2016 as Outlook 2016 now uses the Exchange Search Index in priority for more consistent search results across various Outlook configurations and Outlook (Web) Mail apps.

To return the previous search behavior that relies on the local Windows Search Index, you can set the registry below:

Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Search
Value name: **DisableServerAssistedSearch**
Value type: REG_DWORD
  Value: 1

(You may need to manually create the registry key it it doesn't exist.)

For your reference(a forum article from MS Technet):

[Outlook 2016 now uses the Exchange Search Index in priority](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2c0d4f35-b84a-48a1-b080-a58ad17493ce/outlook-2016-now-uses-the-exchange-search-index-in-priority?forum=outlook)

Comment: Would this change the default behavior, or disable Server Assisted Search at all?

Comment: @sancho.s, It will disable server assisted search at all. Instead, it will use search results from Windows search service.

Comment: Is there any way to search, by default locally, and optionally (preferably with just one or a few mouse clicks) in the server?

Comment: I am afraid there is no way to search local first then sever. You can vote for this post(https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/18870043-please-add-an-option-to-have-outlook-search-emails) in the Outlook UserVoice forum. Hopefully the thread with high votes can be heard and considered by the product team.

Comment: Great answer! Hit the nail in the head.

Comment: Glad to be of help :D Do you mind marking the reply as answer?

Answer (score 2):

A small correction is required for the above registry path.
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Search